# MariaDB ignores ORDER BY in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I installed new version of MariaDB and got problem with sorting php-script:

```
$this->db->query("
    SET @v:=0;
    UPDATE `users` AS `c1`
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `id`, (@v:=@v+2) AS `ord2`, `name`, `parent` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `parent`='0' ORDER BY `ord` ASC) AS `c2`
    ON `c1`.`id` = `c2`.`id`
    SET `c1`.`ord` = `c2`.`ord2`
    WHERE `c1`.`parent` = '0'
");
```

In particular script sets order of entries in `users` table sorting them by `ord`:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord | name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   5 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   7 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   9 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

I'm not familiar with SQL and after long hours of searching and tests I, as it seems to me, found out the SQL-query that doesn't work right:

```
SELECT `id`, (@v:=@v+2) AS `ord2`, `name`, `parent` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `parent`='0' ORDER BY `ord` ASC;
```

In previous version of MariaDB (5.5.5-10.1.25) the query gives entries sorted by initial order (`ord`):

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord2| name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   4 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   6 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   8 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

In new version (10.6.3) result is:

```
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
| id | ord2| name               | parent |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
|  2 |   2 | admin              |      0 |
| 10 |   4 | manager            |      0 |
| 12 |   8 | user               |      0 |
| 11 |   6 | dev                |      0 |
+----+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

I tried to set ORDER BY param `ord` to `name` and `id`, but result was the same. It seems like col `ord2` filled with even numbers is always sorted by `id` in ascending order.

How should I rewrite the query or the script to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest MariaDB versions you can use window function row_number in next way:

```
select 
    id,
    (row_number() over (order by ord))*2 ard2,
    name,
    parent
from tbl;
```

[MariaDB query test here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=cdad57b0223a0e7a6a916f36e331ef2d&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution fix my problem. And your answer helps me find more information about ROW NUMBER function that can replace ORDER BY in subqueries